# Modifying Makefile to produce assembly files

Tags: assembly, makefile, avr

I'm a newbie of make, and I can't add .asm output to already existing makefile. I would like to make makefile to produce .asm files (using AVR-GCC -S) to all of the .c files. Could you help me figure it out?

```
    # AVR model
MMCU = atmega16
# Clock frequency
F_CPU = 16000000
# Programmer model
PROGRAMMER = usbasp
PROGRAMMER_PORT = usb
# Output file name
PROJECT = main
# Sources files
SOURCES = main.c\
                cross/drivers/internals/GPIO/GPIO.c \
                cross/drivers/internals/PPI/PPI8Bit.c \
                cross/drivers/internals/USART/USART_0.c \

CC = avr-gcc
ASM = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
CDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL
CFLAGS = $(CDEFS)
CFLAGS += -mmcu=$(MMCU) -g -Os -Wall
OBJS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)
ASMS = $(SOURCES:.c=.s)

$(PROJECT).hex: $(PROJECT).out
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -R .eeprom $(PROJECT).out $(PROJECT).hex

$(PROJECT).out:  $(OBJS)
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@ -lm
$.o:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
##???
$.s:%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -S $< -o $@

asm: $(OBJS_S)

flash: $(PROJECT).hex
    avrdude -c $(PROGRAMMER) -P $(PROGRAMMER_PORT) -p $(MMCU) -U flash:w:$(PROJECT).hex

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS)
    rm -f $(PROJECT).out
    rm -f $(PROJECT).hex

.PHONY: clean program_flash
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When asking for help please always include the version of make, the exact (cut and paste) command you typed, and a precise description of exactly what the problem is (with cut and paste output if appropriate).  Saying "I can't do it" doesn't help us understand what the problem is.

These are definitely not right:

```
$.o:%.c
  ...
$.s:%.c
```

[Pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) use `%` on *both* sides of the `:`, like this:

```
%.o:%.c
  ...
%.s:%.c
```

Second, you put your asm files into this variable:

```
ASMS = $(SOURCES:.c=.s)
```

but then you list a completely different variable as the prerequisite of the `asm` target:

```
asm: $(OBJS_S)
```

This `OBJS_S` variable is never defined as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

When compiling a C/C++ file (or from any other language for that matter), GCC always produces intermediate assembly code.  This is saved in some tmp directory (except you are using -pipe). If you want GCC to save this intermediate assembly in .s files, there is option `-save-temps` (in addition to intermediate assembly, this also saves the preprocessed sources in .i (C) resp. .ii (C++)).  You can add additional comments that contain C/C++ code to guide you; use `-fverbose-asm` for that.  In the case you are using LTO (`-flto`) etc., new compiler versions only write the lto gibberish to assembly (to be picked up by the lto compiler at link time).  In order to save assembly code in that case, add `-ffat-lto-objects`.  Notice however, that this is not the final asm when you are linking with -flto (which calls the lto compiler that compiles lto gibberish to asm).  The final asm can be seen with -save-temps in some of the ltrans dumps. You can also use `-save-temps=obj` and `-save-temps=src` which saves the intermediate files close to your object files resp. your source files (in case that makes a difference).